# How to prevent position:fixed from breaking flexbox justify-content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

How do I prevent `position:fixed` of a parent container from breaking its `justify-content` attribute?
I am trying to create a fixed menu bar using flexbox.

Example
https://codepen.io/dnguyencode/pen/XWjgxKG

```
<style>
*{
    border: 1px black solid;
}


.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    // position: fixed;
    height: 100px;

}
</style>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav__logo">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="" id="header-img">
            </div>
            <div class="nav__linkList">
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <a href="#sect1" class="nav-link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect2" class="nav-link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect3" class="nav-link">Click Me</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure how the navigation should look, but if you remove flexbox from .nav and just set to the child class .nav__linkList, the flexbox would work with all properties.

Comment: You need to specify a width to the `nav`

Comment: @Paulie_D When I specify the width of the nav bar, it causes clipping. You can see it here: https://codepen.io/dnguyencode/pen/XWjgxKG

Comment: @lortschi This is not what I was looking for. The navigation tag contain the logo image & the navbar links, with logo in one end and link in the other. I want both of these elements to be fixed.

Comment: Remove justify-content: space-between; on .nav and set margin-right: 'your-px-amount' on .nav__logo. Then you can set your exact distance between logo and nav. The clipping is then no more visible.

Comment: @lortschi That's not a solution as the point of using justify-content:spacebetween is to make the navigation responsive.

Comment: I doubt you can spacebetween in this case proper control. But margin-left you can pass breaking points via media query as % e.q. Or other solution flex-wrap your .nav container and pass separate flex: width to each child.

Answer (score 0):

Add width 100% to image, then it will fit in properly.

````
<style>
*{
    border: 1px black solid;
}
.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="nav__logo">
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="" id="header-img" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="nav__linkList">
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <a href="#sect1" class="nav-link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect2" class="nav-link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect3" class="nav-link">Click Me</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>```
````

Comment: This seems to cause clipping. Part of the nav bar went missing. Do you know what happened here? > https://codepen.io/dnguyencode/pen/XWjgxKG

Comment: Add width 100% to the image, now image is taking its original width. It should take width of its parent div

Comment: https://codepen.io/pranjalkoshti/pen/dypRLeE Check here

Comment: do you know how to fix the image and make it responsive (resize according to parent container.

Comment: Check the link shared, image is 100% means is responsive, play around a little bit with flex properties, notice that I added flex 2 and flex 1 for logo div and links div resp, see how it changes dimensions of image,  arrangement of divs